# How do I uniquely identify enabled/disabled objects in QTP

Tags: automation, ui-automation, qtp, hp-uft

In my application, I have to verify if a particular button is enabled or not. It gets enabled after I fill in certain values.

But, the problem is the properties for the button is EXACTLY the same when its enabled and disabled. (Even the value of isEnabled is false in both cases)

If I try to click on that button, it gets clicked in both cases (even it gets clicked when its disabled but however since its disabled nothing happens)

So, how do I proceed now?

Comment: Can you post the html for both cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure all the properties are exactly same? Do you have access to the color property? Font color or background color. If yes, then I am sure color for enabled and disabled button would be different. If this is the case- viola!

Answer (score 0):

You can check the height and width of the object to identify the object .
Mostly in masked scenario it will be zero .

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the button is disabled, then clicking it will yield no result. If this is for a web-based application, then you can include a checkpoint in your code to check that no request/response is sent from the webpage. (ie. no communication is initiated from the browser).